# How do I diffput a deleted line?

Tags: vimdiff

When viewing a diff of two files in Vim, you can put changes from the source file to the destination file by pressing <kbd>d</kbd> then <kbd>p</kbd>, or by running `:diffput`. However, this doesn't work if the change is a deleted line.

For example, let's look at the contents of the file `one.txt`:

```
a
b
c
```

And the contents of the file `two.txt`:

```
a
c
```

If I open the two files in diff mode (`vimdiff one.txt two.txt`), and I have my cursor on the file `two.txt`, how do I push the change (that is, the deleted line) from `two.txt` to `one.txt`? The only way to do it seems to be to change the focus to the other window `one.txt` and then run <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>, but that is a lot of keystrokes, especially if you have multiple windows open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the cursor *beneath* the deleted block, i.e., in your case on line `c` in the file `two.txt`, and press <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>.